# Image path react-native: Unable to resolve module

Tags: react-native, module, path

I am getting this error when trying to add a static image as an icon in the app. All my assets are in the `assets` folder in the root directory. I have named my app as `jobsicle` to use absolute paths rather than `../../assets/...`. When I run my app I am getting this error :

```
The development server returned response error code: 500

URL: http://192.168.56.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&strict=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=expo/tools/hashAssetFiles
```

> Body: {"from":"C:\Users\Shahzaib
>   Rahim\Documents\work\jobsicle\screens\employer\EmployerHomeScreen.js","to":"jobsicle/assets/icons/bottomNav/employer_home_green@1x.png","message":"Unable
>   to resolve module
>   `jobsicle/assets/icons/bottomNav/employer_home_green@1x.png` from
>   `C:\\Users\\Shahzaib
>   Rahim\\Documents\\work\\jobsicle\\screens\\employer\\EmployerHomeScreen.js`:
>   Module does not exist in the module map\n\nThis might be related to
>   https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try
>   the following:\n  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman
>   watch-del-all`.\n  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf
>   node_modules && npm install`.\n  3. Reset packager cache: `rm -fr
>   $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start --
>   --reset-cache`.","name":"UnableToResolveError","type":"UnableToResolveError","errors":[{}]}

Why am I encountering this error?

Comment: did you try running npm start again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by renaming the icons without having special characters such as `@` and `_`. Apparently having a filename with special characters triggers an error in the Node runtime.